# Unable to update ADT in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed Eclipse ADT Bundle. When I open the eclipse window, I get a message saying "Update your ADT". But no updates are available. I checked online and tried to install in the "Install New Software" option. But still I am getting error message saying " Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 21.1.0.201302060051 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.1.0.201302060051)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [21.1.0.201302060051]".

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had once the problem, and if you don't have 50 open projects, the fastest way to resolve it is donwloading and reinstalling ADT Bundle.